# Why does a SOQL query have different results from the record page?

Tags: soql

I am running this query.

```
select id, name, Community_Partner__c, Community_Partner__r.Name from Engagements__c where id = 'a005e000003wKuwAAE'
```

and the results returned show that the lookup field community partner is empty.  Yet when I go to the record page there are 4 community partners.

Am I missing something? If I do the same thing in the sandbox the results are showing but not in production.

Data model : Engagement has a lookup field called community partners. The schema is attached.

Image of the record page
[image]

Results of the query.
[image: Results]

Thanks!

After suggestion..

[image]

[image: schema]

Result of new query..
[image]

Answer (score 2):

You are checking incorrect information with SOQL. I don't know your data model, but `Engagements__c.Community_Partner__c` seems like a main partner or something like this.

To get info you need either
`select id, name FROM Community_Partner__c where Engagements__c = 'a005e000003wKuwAAE'`, or `select id, name, (SELECT Id, Name FROM Community_Partners__r) from Engagements__c where id = 'a005e000003wKuwAAE'`.

You need to select all Community Partners that are related to Engagement, not a single Community Partner that is specified on the record.

**UPDATE**

after seeing the schema I would suggest following query to discover what you have on the org.

```
SELECT Id, Name, Engagement__c, Engagement__r.Name
FROM Community_Partner__c
LIMIT 200
```

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/126754/discussion-between-pauline-and-ytiq).